# typename outside of template

Tags: c++, templates

This in VS2010sp1 doesn't compile (it does compile with gcc 4.6 though):

```
template<class T>
struct Upcast;

template<>
struct Upcast<signed char>
{
    typedef signed short type;
};

template<>
struct Upcast<char>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_signed<char>::value,short, unsigned short>::type type;
};

int main()
{
    Upcast<char>::type a;
    return 0;
}
```

Error from VS:

```
Error   1   error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration
```

Which team is right? VS or gcc?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

VS is right on C++03. GCC is right on C++0x.

Now it may be sensible for GCC to also allow this in C++03 mode (there are many things real compilers don't diagnose in C++03 mode that are actually only valid in C++0x), and it may as-well sensible for VS to reject it in C++03 mode.

It doesn't matter anymore whether or not a use of `typename QualifiedName` happens in a template or not, in C++0x. That is, the following is perfectly legal for C++0x:

```
#include<vector>

int main() {
  typename std::vector<int> v;
}
```

In C++03, `typename` could only be used inside of a template. And the explicit specialization in your code is not a template. There are no `template<typename T ...>` clauses (all parameters in your code are fixed).

Comment: GCC also gives the error when compiling without `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @KennyTM thanks, good to know. What GCC version do you use? I have GCC4.6.0, which accepts my code sample in C++03 mode even with `-pedantic`.

Comment: @Johan any idea how to bypass this unnatural constraint?

Comment: @Johan my solution? Just remove typename. But this also makes me think that if in this case compiler can do without typename why can't it do without it in a primary template or partial specialization?

Comment: @Johannes, a practical question first: So `typename` should be removed from this code, and it will then compile anywhere? It might be useful of you had put "_the explicit specialization in your code is not a template_" at the start of your answer. I suspect it's the main lesson to be learned; would you agree?

Comment: @Johannes: Just tested again. Looks like gcc rejects it on 4.2 and accepts it on 4.5.

Answer (score 8):

As per C++03, `typename` and `template` keywords are not allowed anywhere outside a template, including explicit (full) template specializations. So MSVC++ is correct as per C++03

As per C++0x this code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case it would seem that VS2010 is right in rejecting the code:

14.6/5

> The keyword typename shall be applied only to qualified names, but those names need not be dependent. The keyword typename shall be used only in contexts in which dependent names can be used. This includes template declarations and definitions but **excludes explicit specialization declarations** and explicit instantiation declarations.